# Forma texto em $('span.texto').text();

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de formatar texto na seguinte linha:

```
$('span.texto').text('Enviamos um email para email@email');
```

Gostaria que ficasse:

Enviamos um email para **email@email**

Tentei

```
$('span.texto').text('Enviamos um email para <b>email@email</b');
```

Mas nao deu ainda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque o `text` por `html`:

```js
$('span.texto').html('Enviamos um email para <b>email@email</b');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="texto"></span>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, deu certinho! Muito obrigado!